# IT Territory control when multiple IT players are involved

Tags: relationships, networking

Scenario:

We are an IT company who services many companies. Recently, one of the bigger companies brought in a 3rd party consultant who works for a group, and they have their own internal IT who likes to keep a tight grip on everything.

We created an exchange account for this user so calendar sharing could be achieved and events placed for them. I just found out that the password was changed and I no longer have access to that account. I had their internal IT group make the required changes I needed done on the account.

While this is not a big issue, it brings up the question for situations that involve more than one IT group. How do you determine who controls what territory?

EDIT: 
In regards to password sharing. The issue here is that they do some different ways of managing calendar and email syncing, so the typical normal way would not work, so I had to surrender the password.

Comment: The client decides.

Comment: _I just found out that the password was changed and I no longer have access to that account_ Does this mean you were password-sharing? In that case maybe the other group should have control...

Comment: *I just found out that the password was changed and I no longer have access to that account* Does this mean you were password-sharing? In that case maybe the other group should terminate your company's access entirely.

Comment: There is no situation where two entities having access to the same account is ever a good idea. Separate your interests, and learn about best security practices. If they performed malicious actions on this account, knowing full well you have access to the password they could of _easily_ blamed you for it, as there would of been little viable way of distinguishing who was in control of the account. (of course logs to IP's matching the office's IP/ISP block could indicate, but its never sure-fire)

Comment: I think your company has some delusions of grandeur. You are a supplier to your clients. If your clients want to handle security of systems (because your company obviously doesn't know how to), then they should be encouraged.

Comment: Isn't someone in charge that could address this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel that this arrangement negatively impacts the services that your company should be providing to the client then you should bring it up to management, who will address the issue through the proper channels.

At the end of the day, however, the client will decide which company gets access to which of their resources.

Comment: Also, what does the contract say?